# Having trouble creating a stored procedure in documentDB

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to create a stored procedure to edit a document in documentDB, and I am using the code as mentioned in this link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/programming

However, I get this error:

mscorlib: TypeError: client.createStoredProcedureAsync is not a function

Is this an issue with my library? (documentdb) I have the following code also.

```
var documentClient = require("documentdb").DocumentClient;

var client = new documentClient("DB URL", { "masterKey": "DB Key" });
```

Is the tutorial not suitable for node.js?

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you mentioned uses the [Node.js SDK with Q Promises](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-node-q) to illustrate syntax and usage of stored procedures, triggers, and UDFs.

So, you'll need to install it via the following command:

```
npm install documentdb-q-promises
```

and change your code from:

```
var documentClient = require("documentdb").DocumentClient;
```

to:

```
var documentClient = require("documentdb-q-promises").DocumentClientWrapper;
```

Comment: Ah i see - is there a similar method to do this by using the current library?

Comment: Yes, you can use the methed `createStoredProcedure` to create a stored procedure in [Node.js SDK for DocumentDB](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-node) . See code sample [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-node/blob/master/samples/ServerSideScripts/app.js#L81).